# Objective C "for" loop to parse a JSON array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, for-loop

I am having troubles parsing the following json array, I guess my problem is that I don't know how to make the "for" loop to go through the json Array. Well this is the Json:

```
 [
  {
   "clavemateria": "TIB1025   ",
   "nombremateria": "PROGRAMACION WEB                                                                     ",
   "nombrecorto": "PROGRAMACION WEB    ",
   "clavegrupo": "9A  ",
   "horalunes": "10001100",
   "horamartes": "10001100",
   "horamiercoles": "10001100",
   "horajueves": "10001100",
   "horaviernes": "10001100"
   },
  {
   "clavemateria": "AEB1011   ",
   "nombremateria": "DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES PARA DISPOSITIVOS MOVILES                                ",
    "nombrecorto": "DES. A. DIS. MOVILES",
    "clavegrupo": "9A  ",
    "horalunes": "11001200",
    "horamartes": "11001200",
    "horamiercoles": "11001200",
    "horajueves": "11001200",
    "horaviernes": "11001200"
   },
   {
    "clavemateria": "AEB1055   ",
    "nombremateria": "PROGRAMACION WEB                                                                      ",
    "nombrecorto": "PROG. WEB           ",
    "clavegrupo": "fD  ",
    "horalunes": "10001100",
    "horamartes": "10001100",
    "horamiercoles": "10001100",
    "horajueves": "10001100",
    "horaviernes": "10001100"
   }
 ]
```

And this is my code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   NSDictionary *jsonRecibido = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datosWeb options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
   NSString *clavemateria, *nombremateria, *nombrecorto, *clavegrupo, *horalunes, *horamartes, *horamiercoles, *horajueves, *horaviernes;



    for(id elemento in jsonRecibido)
    {
      clavemateria = [elemento objectForKey:@"clavemateria"];
      nombremateria = [elemento objectForKey:@"nombremateria"];
      nombrecorto = [elemento objectForKey:@"nombrecorto"];
      clavegrupo = [elemento objectForKey:@"clavegrupo"];
      horalunes = [elemento objectForKey:@"horalunes"];
      horamartes = [elemento objectForKey:@"horamartes"];
      horamiercoles = [elemento objectForKey:@"horamiercoles"];
      horajueves = [elemento objectForKey:@"horajueves"];
      horaviernes = [elemento objectForKey:@"horaviernes"];

      //Objeto para guardar las variables.
      FatherClass *group = [[FatherClass alloc]init];
      [group setSubjectKey:clavemateria];
      [group setLongNameSubject:nombremateria];
      [group setShortNameSubject:nombrecorto];
      [group setGroupKey:clavegrupo];
      [group setMondaySchedule:horalunes];
      [group setThursdaySchedule:horajueves];
      [group setWednesdaySchedule:horamiercoles];
      [group setTuesdaySchedule:horamartes];
      [group setFridaySchedule:horaviernes];

      [groupArray addObject:group];
   }
 }
```

In the for loop I add the group object into my Father class, So, what would the propper way to go through this array?

Comment: That's an array of dictionaries; so `NSDictionary *jsonRecibido =` is wrong.  Otherwise the code should work.

Comment: how it would be then @trojanfoe

Comment: Use `NSArray` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of old style syntax and other things you could improve here...

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // this is an NSArray not an NSDictionary
    NSArray *jsonRecibido = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datosWeb options:kNilOptions error:NULL];

    // The elements of the array ARE NSDictionary
    for(NSDictionary *elemento in jsonRecibido)
    {
        // Use modern Obj-C syntax to get value from dictionary
        // Place them directly in the array.
        // No need to store them in separate strings.

        //Objeto para guardar las variables.
        FatherClass *group = [FatherClass new];
        [group setSubjectKey:elemento[@"clavemateria"]];
        [group setLongNameSubject:elemento[@"nombremateria"]];
        [group setShortNameSubject:elemento[@"nombrecorto"]];
        [group setGroupKey:elemento[@"clavegrupo"]];
        [group setMondaySchedule:elemento[@"horalunes"]];
        [group setThursdaySchedule:elemento[@"horamartes"]];
        [group setWednesdaySchedule:elemento[@"horamiercoles"]];
        [group setTuesdaySchedule:elemento[@"horajueves"]];
        [group setFridaySchedule:elemento[@"horaviernes"]];

        [groupArray addObject:group];
    }
}
```

This should work and also shorten the code and make it easier to see what is happening :D

Answer (score 0):

Swap

```
NSDictionary *jsonRecibido = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datosWeb options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
```

with

```
NSArray *jsonRecibido = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datosWeb options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
```